# XML 45° Effect-Overlay

Tags: android, xml

I'm just struggling around with a simple effect, that I would like to create directly within the XML layout file....

[image: Sample effect]

As you can see I just want to create a 45° overlay effect. But I'm not able to do so. Maybe you can lead me into the right direction...

Code of round linearlayout (left side):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="95dp" android:background="@drawable/semicircle_layout">
</LinearLayout>
```

semicircle_layout

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#393a3f"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#27262c"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:angle="45" android:startColor="#000000"  android:endColor="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: i dont think its simple,  at least when it comes to xml customization,  i am afraid you cannot do that in xml

Comment: This seems like something easier to do on a canvas object with drawArc and drawLine.  The xml drawable commands are relatively limited compared to that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply pskink. So I don't feel that bad ;).
GabeSechan thank you too. I'll try this. It's a new point to start with.